# Deleting a row in datagrid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I want to Delete a row in the Gridview which is in the update panel . But instead of the command button ., i took a link button to get a confirmation message. Now if I press ok then the record should be deleted (both from db and frm girdview). I know how to delete from db but not when linkbutton is pressed, and deleting the record. And also the gridview is in update panel.so it should be reflected.

A sample code is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: kundur: provide your code please ..

Comment: ok sure i will take your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `RowCommand` event of gridview, like...

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {            
        e.CommandArgument  -- this return Data Key Value
//Deletion Code goes here.....
var brochureToDelete = (from b in dataContext.ArticleBrochures where b.ArticleId == ArticleId select b).FirstOrDefault(); 
if (brochureToDelete != null) 
{ 
dataContext.ArticleBrochures.DeleteOnSubmit(brochureToDelete);
dataContext.SubmitChanges(); 
bindBrochureGridView(ArticleId);
// if your gridview in updatepanel
//Call update method of UpdatePanel
//UpdatePanel.Update();
 }
}
```

Comment: We are just deleting the row from teh db as you and me hav done but i need the row to be deletd from the gridview as well right

Comment: @manasareddy.kundur: `bindBrochureGridView(ArticleId);` rebinds the gridview. re-bind the gridview

Comment: @Manasarelly; Show your complete form Design. then I will able to understand your problem.

Comment: I have this <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="brochureUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" > and also made brochureupdatepanel.update() after the bind But the row from the gridview doesnt delete

Comment: make sure it exist in the DB ? I think the probelem in your deletion code that LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Akta I found whats  the problem . All the rows in the gridview belong to the same id. So i cant delete records based on id. either should delete based on the index. How can I get the selected index  of the girdview and ddelete it .

Comment: can you plz update your question with complete cs code. and gridview formDesign. ?

Comment: e.CommandArgument will return the current row primary key column name, if you specify DataKeyNames="PrimarykeyColumnName" in your gridview properties.

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
        String productId = row.Cells[0].Text; // I suposed your product Id in very first column in gridview
        //Delete Code goes here..........
        ...........................
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and i checked the data is deleted from the db but update panel doent get updated even after doing updatepanel1.update()

Answer (score 0):

Set `PK_ID` to link button's command args like that

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btn_manage" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("PK_ID") %>'
                                OnCommand="btn_manage_click">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

and access this `PK_ID` on event

```
protected void btn_manage_click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string ID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

    //you delete code and gridview bind code
}
```

Comment: I have written code to delete and binded it but: var brochureToDelete = (from b in dataContext.ArticleBrochures
                                            where b.ArticleId == ArticleId
                                            select b).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (brochureToDelete != null)
                    {
                        dataContext.ArticleBrochures.DeleteOnSubmit(brochureToDelete);
                        dataContext.SubmitChanges();
                        bindBrochureGridView(ArticleId); And in the bindbrochureGrodview I have :

Comment: var brochureList = (from brochure in dataContext.ArticleBrochures
                                    where brochure.ArticleId == id
                                    select new ArcticleBrochure
                                    {
                                        ArticleId = brochure.ArticleId.ToString(),
                                        FileName = brochure.FileName

                                    }).ToList();
               brochureGridView.DataSource = brochureList;
               brochureGridView.DataBind();

Comment: I have this <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="brochureUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" > and also made brochureupdatepanel.update() after the bind

Comment: Are you setting the DataSource of the grid before or after the delete, if before then you will need to refresh it after deletion.

Answer (score 0):

bind the linkbutton id as the primary key. On client clicking the link button save that id in a hidden field. This hidden field value will be the id of row to be deleted.

Then on the server click of link button delete the row corresponding to the hidden field value

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have a method which sends a delete query.

Make a `RowDeleting` event handler, pass your row index using `e.RowIndex` to the delete method.

Use this `e.RowIndex` to write a query to delete the 'n'th row of your table. and then bind the data to your gridView.