# Deleting a row in Gridview without having DataKey value

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting a row in datagrid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028111/deleting-a-row-in-datagrid-view)

Hi.,

I have gridview in updatepanel and I do not have any datakey values. I have a `LinkButton` delete. When I press this, the row should delete. But as said I don't have any datakey values. so I cant use `commandArgument`.
How can I do this?

Any ideas?
Thanks.